# SOAP REQUEST USING Savon Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, savon

I have savon `version =>1`

and my code is here

```
require 'savon'
 client = Savon::Client.new "http://midoffice.makemytrip.com/MMT_Webs_CreateIncident/MMT_Webs_CreateIncident.asmx"
response = client.do_simple do |soap|
 soap.body = {
  :FirstName =>"ravendra"
 }
end
```

and it gives us

```
undefined method `do_simple' for #<Savon::Client:0xb6c87178>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call a request method as parameter as method you want to call as like below.

```
   require 'savon'
 client = Savon::Client.new "http://abc.com"
response = client.request :do_simple do
 soap.body = {
  :FirstName =>"ravendra"
 }
end
```

This http://fagiani.github.io/savon/ helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call do_simple SOAP action on http://abc.com. Are you sure this action is there in WSDL?

Comment: http://midoffice.makemytrip.com/MMT_Webs_CreateIncident/MMT_Webs_CreateIncident.asmx is my url